# Why does it look like overlapping when painting, but on UV map, are not overlapping?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, texture-paint-mode

When I am texture painting, I am noticing locations where painting at one location also paints in another location.

I have noticed that this is a very common issue when having overlapping face. But even after getting rid of overlapping faces, I am still seeing this occur when faces on the UV editor are close, but not overlapping. Why does this occur, and how can I detect these issues beforehand?

Comment: It's normal that it happens if the UV faces are overlapping, if they are not anymore maybe check the Bleeding value, make sure that it's not too high?

Comment: Where is this value, I have never heard of it?

Comment: N panel > Tool > Options > Bleed

Comment: It looks like that was it. It was on 2 pixels, and changed it to 1 pixel and don't see it anymore. TYSM!

Comment: maybe you should set a larger margin when you unwrap then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that it happens if the UV faces are overlapping, if they are not anymore check the *Bleed* value (*N panel > Tool > Options > Bleed*), make sure that it's not too high. Also maybe increase the margin between the UV islands when you unwrap.